# Angular Test a controller that use RouteParams

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, routes, parameters, karma-runner

I need to test a Controller that use `$routeParams` to define it action. Maybe it is a test problem, or is wrong the way I wrote the controller, so now I can't write  a test.

Here is my controller

```
angular.module('cmmApp')
.controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, Userservice) {

    //if a user id is set retrieve user information
    if(typeof $routeParams.id !== 'undefined'){

        var loader = $ionicLoading.show({content: "Retrieving user data"});

        var user = Userservice.get({id: $routeParams.id}).$promise;

        user.then(function(res){
            console.log(res);
            $scope.user = res.user;
            loader.hide();
        });
    }
    //else create an empty resource
    else {
        $scope.user = new Userservice;
    }
});
```

Basically I only want to load a resource if an id is provided is `$routeParams`, else create an empty resource.

And here is the test:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: UserCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('cmmApp'));

  var UserCtrl,
      scope,
      routeParams;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $routeParams, Userservice) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    routeParams = $routeParams;
    UserCtrl = $controller('UserCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });

    console.log("routeParams");
    routeParams = {id: 8490394};
    console.warn(routeParams);
  }));

  it('should create an epmty user', function () {
    console.log(scope.user);
    expect(scope.user).toEqual({});

  });

});
```

When I run `grunt test` karma reply:

```
Controller: UserCtrl should create an epmty user FAILED
    Expected {  } to equal {  }.
    Error: Expected {  } to equal {  }.
    at null.<anonymous>    (/Users/carlopasqualicchio/Sites/CMM_Ionic/test/spec/controllers/user.js:28:24)
```

I'm wonering how to tell karma to change `$routeParams.id`before a test to run, and assign a different value in two different test (I need to set it to null in the first, and to a value to the other).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks, Matt.

Comment: Have you tried assigning a value to `$routeParams.id`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can pass a custom `$routeParams` object using the second argument of `$controller` (locals object), i.e. the same way you pass the `$scope`:

```
UserCtrl = $controller('UserCtrl', {
    $scope: scope,
    $routeParams: {id: '...'}
});
```

Comment: This works, so I used to describe function to test my controller with and without the params. Thanks a lot.